# Create an external link in a comment in Asana

Tags: hyperlink, asana

I'm trying to create a link to a document in a shared company drive.  I cannot upload the document (confidentiality) to Asana servers.  Also, I am not referring to a "@" + task or person type of link.  I do not want to link to a workspace or a task.  I am referring to a "O:\folder\keydoc.doc" type of link.  I can paste the link as plain text, but it would be much better if it could be clicked directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately we do not support this at this time. Even if we did provide support for links, linking to local files is a security risk and so we probably wouldn't support that use case.

Comment: Is that still true?!? I really can't imagine that you cannot insert links in comments ...